# memory allocation for c_str function in string class

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

I have a member function of a class which is defined below, say

```
int x(std::string &a, std::string &b) {
    char *ptr = another_member.getStringMember().c_str() //I am storing the pointer 
    cout << ptr << endl;
    a="hello";
    cout << ptr << endl; 
}
```

The output is

> StringMember
>
> Hello

Can you please explain why this happens ?? Thanks

Comment: We have no idea what's happening without seeing another_member, or how you're calling this function.

Comment: one bug in your code: `c_str()` function returns `const char*`

why it prints what it prints? it should be exactly what `another_member.getStringMember` contains. And apparently you have some aliasing as well.

Comment: another member is just another class and getStringMember just returns a string, that string has nothing to do with a and there is no aliasing. 
regarding the const_char *, my bad, I did not the const_cast<char *> that I had done

Answer (score 5):

Most likely because `another_member.getStringMember` and `a` are the same string.

In this case it is not actually legal to use `ptr` after the string has been modified with `a="hello";` because mutating operations can make the previously obtained pointer invalid.

Comment: +1:  the pointer returned by `c_str()` is not guaranteed to be valid after any operation has been performed on the source string.

Comment: The pointer returned from c_str() may be invalidated at the and of expression as c_str() is not required to return char *, it is allowed to return temporary object convertible to char *.

Comment: @John :  I checked the documentation and I agree that it says that the pointer is not valid after any other operation on that string object. But as you can see I have not touched that string at all. All I have done is assigned "hello" to a completely different string

Comment: @Vinayak: From the code we can't see if the strings are different or not. `a` is a reference to some string, we don't know which. - Also, if `getStringMember` is actually a function returning a string by value, things get a lot fishier. Perhaps after assigning to `a` it gets the same memory location allocated as the temporary string.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, do you call

```
x(another_member.getStringMember, fooBar);
```

?

c_str() returns internal pointer of string object which became invalid as soon as you modify the source string

Comment: I agree, but I have not touched or modified the source string at all other than printing it out. All I have done is assigned "hello" to a different string. Seems like the string class gave up the memory that the pointer pointed to and that memory was used up store the const "hello"

Answer (score 1):

You are not guaranteed that ptr is still usable after the `a="hello"` line (since it looks like they are the same string).  In your case, since Hello was smaller, and the string wasn't being shared, it looks like it reused the space.

This is implementation specific behavior.  It could have easily crashed.

Comment: They are not the same string, the string 'a' had nothing to do with the string returned by another_member.getStringElement

Answer (score 1):

The temp std::string from another_member.getStringElement() goes out of scope after the line is executed.  Change

```
char *ptr = another_member.getStringMember().c_str();
```

to

```
std::string s = another_member.getStringMember();
const char *ptr = s.c_str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to do `another_member.getStringElement().c_str()` as against `another_member.getStringElement.c_str()`.